# Install issues - Flask with Virtualenv

Tags: pip, virtualenv

I am trying to use virtualenv to install flask. I activate virtualenv by using command

```
$. venv/bin/activate
```

Then I try command

```
(venv)$pip install flask
```

But I am getting an error

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask': Permission denied
```

pip version `1.0` from `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (python 2.7), virtualenv version `1.7.1.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using using `pip` from your `virtualenv` but the one that is installed system-wide.
This is how it should looks like for `virtualenv`:

```
dm@Z580:~/workspace$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
dm@Z580:~/workspace$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)dm@Z580:~/workspace$ which python
/home/dm/workspace/venv/bin/python
(venv)dm@Z580:~/workspace$ which pip
/home/dm/workspace/venv/bin/pip
(venv)dm@Z580:~/workspace$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /home/dm/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```